# Explain why there is a unique function $y$, deﬁned on some interval $I$ around $x = 1$, that satisﬁes the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Explain why there is a unique function $y$, deﬁned on some interval $I$ around $x = 1$, that satisﬁes $xy' = \cos(xy) + 3e^{(y+x^2)}$ for all $x \in I , y(1) = 2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.

Comment: It seems your problem needs to use the theorem of the  implicit function. What do you think about it?

Comment: I am not too sure about it , can u teach me it , thanks

Comment: I think implicit function fits for it

Comment: Write the eqn in the form $y'=f(x,y)$ and note that in a nbhd of $x=1,\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

In the  right halfplane $\Omega:=\{(x,y)\>|\>x>0\}$ you can write your ODE in the form
$$y'={\cos(xy)+3\exp(y+x^2)\over x}=:f(x,y)\ .$$
The right hand side $f$ is continuously differentiable in $\Omega$. Therefore any point $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that
$$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq C|y_1-y_2|\qquad\bigl((x,y_1), (x,y_2)\in U\bigr)$$
for some Lipschitz constant $C>0$. Under these circumstances any IVP
$$y'=f(x,y),\qquad y(x_0)=y_0$$
for given $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$ has exactly one solution, by the standard existence/uniqueness theorem for ODEs. This solution is "globally unique"; its graph will go the boundary of $\Omega$, or to infinity.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.